# Azure Dev Ops react-scripts test hangs forever

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run my react app's tests in Azure Dev Ops I can't figure out how to make the execution stop after the tests run. It just hangs there, holding the pipeline in running mode forever. It's a simple create-react-app application which has a couple of tests. Below is my pipeline's YAML:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- script: npm run citest

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'react'
    targetPath: './build'
```

I had just "- script: npm test" on the test step but, following instructions [in the facebook github](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests) I created a new test script (called citest): `set CI=true && react-scripts test a` but it still does not work. I get the below output in the dev ops console and the task just keeps running forever:

```
> set CI=true && react-scripts test a
PASS src/components/landing/landing.test.js (6.008s)
PASS src/components/navbar/NavBar.test.js
PASS src/components/app/App.test.js
Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.573s
Ran all test suites matching /a/i.
```

I've run out of ideas on what to try - any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update the script like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "citest":"CI=true react-scripts test"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that but the tests don't seem to have actually run, this is the full output (and it says <1s to run while it'd normally take 5s at least:
`> --------@0.0.1 citest /home/vsts/work/1/s
> set CI=true react-scripts test

##[section]Finishing: run tests`

Comment: @YuriW the value is "CI=true react-scripts test" instead of "set CI=true react-scripts test" (remove set)

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't notice that! Seems to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue resolved it by placing this in my pipeline YAML file:

```
- script: set CI=true&&npm test
  displayName: Test
```

Official docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#continuous-integration

Comment: +1 for setting this as part of the pipeline execution (yaml) instead of the app (package.json) - also worth noting that this is the correct syntax for Windows build agents only.