# Azure React Test not creating XML output for Azure test results reporting

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently i am trying to create a test report when I build my react app in azure but I am getting:

```
##[warning]No test result files matching **/TEST-*.xml were found.
Finishing: npm install and build
```

when I run

```
npm run citest a
```

here is my test script and coverage

Here is my yml file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm run citest a
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "build-deploy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "citest": "CI=true react-scripts test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @kevin, I feel like the comment is a duplicate of the code block in the question. If that's the case, could you maybe remove that comment? And could you write a 1-sentence summary for the code block explaining what it's supposed to do, please? Just a bit more detail for people to understand what's going on. :)

Comment: @FlorianGolemo Thanks, I think its a bit easier to understand now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I also looking if the react test framework needs a logger. I then went and installed mocha and mocha junit reporter. I was able to run the tests again but not get an XML output file.

Comment: @Kevin, You need to check if you have generate any test result, you need share the log about the `npm run citest a`, so that we could to know if you have generate the test result correct, or you do not set the task `PublishTestResults` correct.

Comment: No test results are generated so there is nothing to publish. It seems the command isnt working to produce a file. I see that with mocha you need a reporter but I am not sure how to do this with the Jest test that gets added as the standard npx create-react-app

Comment: @Kevin, I am not  familiar with React Test, so I could not understand the argument `a` in the command line `npm run citest a`, have you tried remove the `a`?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047477/azure-dev-ops-react-scripts-test-hangs-forever